# How to find the projection of something onto V?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

Should I row reduce the three matrices and get the answer through that? First I thought I should multiply the first two matrices, and then multiply the product of that onto the third, but the dimensions are not right.

I really don't know what to do. Also, the projection formula is not working out for me if that's the right thing to use.

Comment: If the projection formula is not working for you, then you're using it wrong. If you show us how you're using it, we can probably find the mistake you're making, and set you on the right road. But in my opinion, you should be using common sense, not formulas. I'll write up an answer to show you what I mean.

Comment: Any thoughts/questions about the solutions that have been posted?

Comment: Earth to coofe: Come in, please.

Answer (score 2):

The projection of a vector $\vec v$ onto the subspace $W = \operatorname{span}(\vec u_1, \vec u_2, \dots)$, where $\vec u_i \bot \vec u_j$ for $i\ne j$, is given by

$$\operatorname{proj}_{W}\vec v = \frac {\vec v \cdot \vec u_1}{\|\vec u_1\|^2}\vec u_1 + \frac {\vec v \cdot \vec u_2}{\|\vec u_2\|^2}\vec u_2 + \cdots$$

So you're essentially breaking $\vec v$ into parts: $\vec v = \vec v_{\| W} + \vec v_{\bot W}$.  But then you can break $\vec v_{\| W}$ into parts as well (as long as your basis for $W$ is orthogonal): $\vec v_{\| W} = \vec v_{\| \vec u_1} + \vec v_{\| \vec u_2} + \cdots$.  Then your projection is just
$$\operatorname{proj}_{W}\vec v = \vec v_{\| W} = \vec v_{\| \vec u_1} + \vec v_{\| \vec u_2} + \cdots $$

Answer (score 1):

Let's let $a=(1/\sqrt2,0,1/\sqrt2)=(\sqrt2/2,0,\sqrt2/2)$, $b=(0,1,0)$, $c=(3,-1,2)$. The space $V$ spanned by $a$ and $b$ is a plane (right?). Imagine dropping a perpendicular from $c$ to that plane; the place where that perpendicular hits the plane, that's the answer you are after (right?). That place is some linear combination of $a$ and $b$, so let's write $$c=ra+sb+d$$ where $r$ and $s$ are real numbers we have to figure out, and $d$ is at right angles to both $a$ and $b$ (because $d$ is the perpendicular we dropped from $c$ to $V$, right?). Now take the dot product of both sides with $a$, expand the right side using the distributive law for dot products over addition, noticing that $a\cdot b=0$, and remembering that $a$ and $d$ are perpendicular; you get $$c\cdot a=ra\cdot a$$ and when you calculate the dot products you have $5\sqrt2/2=r$, so there's your value of $r$. Now, what do you suppose you do to get the value of $s$? And then what's the answer?